# converting a textbox into Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, ienumerable

I'm trying to convert a textbox entry into a Dictionary of double, double.  i.e.

Input text is:

> 1,63
>   2,31
>   3,78
>   4,83

I'm then splitting the row by a comma (,).

I've got the code below - but the IEnumerable isnt working. Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
 string input = txtInput.Text;
    List<string> list = new List<string>(
                               input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    IEnumerable<Dictionary<double, double>> dict = list.Select(row => row.Split(','))
    .Select(pair => new Dictionary<string, string>(double.Parse(pair[0]), double.Parse(pair[1])));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want:

```
var dictionary = input.Lines
                      .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                      .ToDictionary(array => double.Parse(array[0]),
                                    array => double.Parse(array[1]));
```

However:

- This assumes the split lines all have the right number of bits (and that you're using a culture which uses "." as the decimal separator; otherwise you're going to have problems)
- This assumes each line has parsable longs in it
- Comparing `double` values for equalty (required by a dictionary) is generally a bad idea. Can you use `int` or `decimal` instead?

Comment: It also assumes there is no digit grouping with commas but one would hope that wouldn't come into play or is that what you meant by your first bullet?

Comment: @AustinSalonen: Sort of, yes.

Comment: @Jon - Thanks for the answer, I'm trying to use the above but getting this error: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Lines' and no extension method 'Lines' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Rob: Sorry, that should have been `txtInput.Lines`. I'd misread your code.